# How to pass a String without quotes to function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
template<typename... Args>
void callJavaScript(const Args&... args) {
     // TO-DO
}

callJavaScript({
   console.log("Hello World")
})
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this with Variadic templates (with/without Macro hack)?

Instead

```
callJavaScript("{
   console.log('Hello World')
}")
```

I want

```
callJavaScript({
   console.log("Hello World")
})
```

Here an example I found that use Macros,

```
#define MULTI_LINE_STRING(a) #a
const char *text = MULTI_LINE_STRING(
  Using this trick(,) you don't need to use quotes.
  Though newlines and     multiple     white   spaces
  will be replaced by a single whitespace.
);
```

Here is my version of this macro,

```
#define createScript(name, ...)                 \
const char *name = #__VA_ARGS__;
```

Comment: I mean, of course not?

Comment: The quotes itself will not been passed, as this, everything is already fine!

Comment: @Peter The compiler complains that there is a use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: @Peter I wonder if there is clang specific trick that can bypass this

Comment: @Peter I have seen a JSON lib (Can't remember name) did this with their own syntax

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without quotes"? Can you show an example where you use the argument?

Comment: @cigien Please see my edit. I have highlighted the part.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not at all clear to me what you want to achieve. Please make a [mre] and describe *precisely* what you want to happen differently.

Comment: @cigien Precisely,  I have this JS interpreter that takes code as a string and to pass a code, I have to wrap the code around quotes. I need to avoid this because of escaping mess. So, I thought that variadic templates  or macros may help to accomplish this. The question seeks an answer about possibility.

Comment: Quite unclear *WHY* you need this! In C++ strings are quoted with `"` and nothing else. What you *really* want to achieve? I have no idea!

Comment: @Klaus Because it allow free-typing without escaping.

Comment: I don't think what you want to achieve can be achieved in C++.  Probably can in Lisp, which actually has powerful macros, unlike C++ token-substitution macro preprocessor, or C++ templates (more powerful than C++ macros, not as powerful as Lisp macros).  Or in a scripting language such as Lua, Python or JavaScript.  But not C++.

Comment: @Eljay I mean you could do something like  on Macro but is it possible to do same with Templates? 

#define createScript(name, ...)                 \
const char *name = #__VA_ARGS__;

Comment: @Eljay The macro compile fine. and print out script.

Comment: *"free-typing without escaping"* You can have that without macros. Use so-called raw strings. `callJavaScript(R"({console.log("Hello World")})")`.

Comment: @Eljay I found the answer and answered it myself. It's 100% possible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

```
void callJavaScript(std::string script) {

    std::cout << script << "\n";
}

#define callJavaScript(...) callJavaScript(#__VA_ARGS__)
```

Now you can call like this,

```
callJavaScript({
   console.log("Hello World")
})
```

You can compile this then it will output

```
{console.log("Hello World")}
```

If anyone has a better way with templates, please do tell.